# How to resize (shrink) a UIView without pixellation?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In my app, I'm creating a full-screen view and then shrinking it down (to about 1/10th of its original size) so that I can later animate it to full-size.  The problem is that the view looks terrible at that size, and is highly pixellated.

Here's the full-size view:
[image]

And here's the shrunken view in-place:
[image]

I'm shrinking the view using `setFrame:` - is there some way to tell iOS to use high-quality interpolation?  Or am I already getting the highest-quality interpolation and this is the best it can do?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend turning the view into an image before you shrink it (I assume currently you have your day view, made up of lots of subviews, which you then just shrink by adjusting the frame).

If you look you'll see this is how Apple achieve it: rather than literally shrinking the view, they will capture the contents of the view as an image, replace the view with that image, and then shrink the image. You'd do this for a number of reasons: efficiency (you can get rid of the shrunken views and replace them with a single UIImageView), speed, and also quality.

To save your UIView as an image you should do something like:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

...then replace your view with the image, and shrink it.

Comment: Actually, my day view is just a single view, with no subviews.  Everything you see on the day view is drawn in `drawRect`.  I have a feeling that I just won't be able to make this work, since even the highest-quality interpolation modes don't let you shrink an image below 25% without loss of information.

Comment: Interesting - it may still be worth giving a go, because if you turn it into an image you can use the in-built interpolation features of Quartz (`CGContextSetInterpolationQuality`). A useful blog post on the business of shrinking images and maintaining quality is here: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/  - again, you'll need a UIImage to do this, so look to the code above for how to turn your view into a CGImageRef